# Does Windowbuilder Pro have an image or graphics control

Tags: image, controls, windowbuilder

I am trying to create a java application that will read a Blob and supporting data from db and display this info on a GUI screen.  I cannot find a image control in the list of controls.

Am I missing something or does Windowbuilder not have the ability to create a GUI containing images?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WindowBuilder is toolset for creating GUI, it doesn't have any built-in control for Image.

Below is one of eclipse articles that nicely explains how one can extend org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas and draw image in paint method, to render image. It also talks about using the custom class in View and plugin project.

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Image-Viewer/Image_viewer.html